# Capital-safe Bonds?

Tags: macroeconomics, finance

What does it mean for a bond not to be capital-safe? I'm having some difficulty in finding in the web any explanation for this expression.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could post here as exact passage where the expression is used.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I've lost track of the sentence. I don't remember anymore in which page it was written... lol

Comment: Anoldmaninthesea. could you provide the work or journal? We can do some digging on our end, but with no information beyond the phrase I don't know that a better answer than @london 's can be provided

Comment: @JasonNichols It was in this book. But honestly, It's probably not worth the digging. I didn't lose much info from the page at the time. ;) http://www.amazon.com/Macroeconomics-Institutions-Instability-Financial-System/dp/0199655790

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try looking into junk bonds as this could be another term for them. Those are bonds below investment grade, they are risky but very high yield debt. You can read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-yield_debt).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/6014)

Comment: The second sentence provides a possible answer,  "not capital-safe bonds" = junk bonds